# Get first char of every string from text file in C

Tags: c, string, file

I'm a bit green in C and whole programming so I need help on task.

My goal is to read text file with random words(strings) and if there are any numbers in strings, change them to first letter of that word/string. Example: "He99llo Im N3w Her3" > "HeHHllo Im NNw HerH"

Questions: 1. How can I read separate strings from text file?
           2. How can I get first letter (not number) from seperate strings?

By the way, I've wrote code, that takes only first char of text file and changes numbers into it, whenever it's number or not, but I dont know how to add code here...

EDIT: Here's the code written code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int Change(FILE *Reading, FILE *Writing){ /*Reads from file and changes numbers into first character of file*/
    int FirstLetter, letter;
    Reading = fopen("C:\\Users\\Rimas\\Desktop\\read.txt", "r");
    Writing = fopen("C:\\Users\\Rimas\\Desktop\\write.txt", "w");

    if (Writing == NULL) {
         printf("I couldn't open write.txt for writing.\n");
         exit(0);
      }

    FirstLetter = getc(Reading);
    if (Reading){
         fprintf(Writing, "%c", FirstLetter);
         while ((letter = getc(Reading)) != EOF){
            if (isdigit(letter)){
                letter = FirstLetter;
            }
            fprintf(Writing, "%c", letter);
         }

    }
    fclose(Reading);
    fclose(Writing);
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    FILE *Reading;
    FILE *Writing;
    Change(Reading, Writing);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Click [Edit], copy-paste your code into the question, select what you have pasted, and click the `[{}]` button in the editor. The code will show up formatted.

Comment: Paste in your code, highlight it, then click the `{}` icon.

Comment: this line in main: Change(Reading, Writing); is passing the current contents of the FILE* type variables and not the address of those variables.  strongly suggest applying the concept of localication of data.  I.E. call Change with no parameters (change the prototype and declaration of Change() also.)  Move the declarations of Reading and Writing variables to the function Change().

Comment: when reading from the file, I suggest reading byte by byte into an array.  (pre set the array to all '\0' each time, before writing chars into it)  stop reading upon finding a space or EOF or '\n'.  Process the one string in the array via a loop. if any char is in the range '0'...'9', replace that char: array[x] - array[0];  write the resulting string to the output file.  always check that at least one char is in the array, so spurious outputs are not made.  You still need to decide what to do if the read string starts with a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some logic to help you:

1. Write a function that accepts a string and converts it as you described. Do this first. And test it well because it is the fundamental part of the program.
2. Now you want to read a text file from main and simply display each word on screen in it's own line.  This is to help you understand how to read words from a file.  I would use `fscanf` for this. Make sure you can read the entire text file and it doesn't crash
3. Now right before printing the word that read in form step 2, call the function from step 1.  This will alter the word and when you print you should get the correct results.

Comment: Thank you for answer, Dan. As a beginner, it is a bit hard for me to understand. I'll try everything again from sratch, step by step.